# Cannot use WifiP2pManager.setDeviceName on Android 11 (Wi-Fi Direct)

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, android-11, wifip2p

My team and I are working with **Wi-Fi Direct** technology on **Android** devices. Until now, the used devices were on Android 8, 9 and 10. We were able to change the Wifi P2P device name of the devices via the **WifiP2pManager.setDeviceName** method.

Unfortunately, from **Android 11** it is impossible to call this method without **system permissions**.

I came here to ask you if there is a solution to change the WifiP2p device name of **non-rooted Android 11** devices programmatically.

If not, is there an **alternative** to Wi-Fi Direct (excepted Bluetooth) supported from Android 8 on which you can start a connection between two (or more) devices, communicate and send files programmatically without a connection to the internet?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe now it's too late but just in case :
We had to use reflection to change our device names.
We're using this implementation :

```
public void setDeviceName(String name) {

        if(name.length() > 32) { // Name size limit is 32 chars.
            name = name.substring(0, 32);
        }

        Class[] paramTypes = new Class[3];
        paramTypes[0] = WifiP2pManager.Channel.class;
        paramTypes[1] = String.class;
        paramTypes[2] = WifiP2pManager.ActionListener.class;
        Object[] argList = new Object[3];
        argList[0] = mChannel; // Your current channel
        argList[1] = name;
        argList[2] = new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wifi name successfully set to " + name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reason) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Device name set failed: reason = " + reason);
            }
        };

        try {
            Method setDeviceNameMethod = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethod("setDeviceName", paramTypes);
            setDeviceNameMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setDeviceNameMethod.invoke(mWifiP2pMgr, argList);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException |
                IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while trying to set device name.\n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```